# 'User' Object has no attribute 'method'

Tags: python, django, web, django-users

I am just playing around with the Django login and logout phase. I have a login page, if the user gets it with 'GET', he gets the form, if he submits the form, it gets submitted to the same `view.login` function. The problem is that when i try to use `' if request.method=='POST'`. I get an error that `'User has not attribute method'`, i don't understand, why does the `'User'` object gets passed instead of the `request` object?
Here's the code of views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Flight,Passenger
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request,"login.html")

    context={
        "flights":Flight.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request,"index.html",context)

def flight(request,flight_id):
    flight= Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
    passengers = flight.passengers.all()
    non_passengers = Passenger.objects.exclude(flight=flight).all()
    context={
    "flight":flight,
    "passengers":passengers,
    "non_passengers":non_passengers
    }
    return render(request,"flight.html",context)

def book(request,flight_id):
    passenger_id = int(request.POST["passenger"])
    flight = Flight.objects.get(pk=flight_id)
    passenger = Passenger.objects.get(pk=passenger_id)
    passenger.flight.add(flight)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("flight",args=(flight_id,)))

def login(request):
    print("\n In LOGIN \n")
    if request.method=='POST':
        print("\n In POST Request \n")
        username = request.POST["name"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request,"login.html")
```

Here's the login page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Name<input type="text" name="name">
        Password<input type="password" name="password">
        <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</body>


</html
```

Here's the error message (Not a full message):

```
AttributeError at /flights/login

'User' object has no attribute 'method'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/flights/login
Django Version:     2.0
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'User' object has no attribute 'method'

Exception Location:     E:\Web\web dev\Practice-code\mysite\flights\views.py in login, line 38
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Mazhar Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.6
Python Path:    

['E:\\Web\\web dev\\Practice-code\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\Mazhar '
 'Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Mazhar Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Mazhar Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Mazhar Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\Mazhar '
 'Ali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 15 Sep 2018 08:15:26 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

    C:\Users\Mazhar Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner

                    response = get_response(request)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Users\Mazhar Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    C:\Users\Mazhar Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response

                        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    E:\Web\web dev\Practice-code\mysite\flights\views.py in login

                    login(user)

         ...
    ▶ Local vars
    E:\Web\web dev\Practice-code\mysite\flights\views.py in login

            if request.method=='POST':

         ...
    ▶ Local vars

Request information
USER

mazharali
GET

No GET data
POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken     

'APmMk0KHsGbdk53l1bgRGCCSaub9OVauHT6ZQvUmK5SOBy9hHcJcEHcHVjPkUs3z'

name    

'Mazhar'

password    

'ali'

FILES

No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
csrftoken   

'zThgQxnzqEMymKDx703M2QihSTSW0r3YGX1tm2xeI3t9DdJtN1w70VS6DIw76YW3'

sessionid   

'gyzu709und6s74mt5c6v1df499570rmp'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You override the django login method by your function `login`. Just rename the

```
def login(request):
```

to something else for example

```
def view_login(request):
```

and don't forget to change imports and urls.

Comment: Oh , i spent hours searching for it. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to help you